# How to force arabic font (TypeFace) to use english numbers Android?

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I am using arabic font in my android app but the numbers is written in arabic , I want to use the same font but numbers still in English Language,Or Customize the TypeFace..Any way??

Comment: you kind of need to say which font you're talking about (including its version number)